# c++ ifstream to char *

Tags: c++, string, pointers, char, ifstream

my code reads a file with ifstream and parse it, now I changed some things and I don't need to read the file, 'cause is read from another place, so I have a char* instead to ifstream... how can I change my code where I use ifstream.get()?
thanks again

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just put your `char *` into an `std::stringstream`.

```
std::stringstream buffer(your_string);
```

You can then use `buffer` almost like it was an `std::ifstream` (you cannot open or close it). Ideally, your parse-method would take a reference to an `std::istream` as parameter, then it would not mind what kind of input-stream it receives:

```
void parse(std::istream & input);
```

Since both `std::ifstream` and `std::stringstream` inherit from `std::istream`, you can pass them as parameters, and your parser runs without modifications.

Comment: Why `stringstream`, and not `istringstream`?  Why the added complexity that he doesn't seem to need?

Comment: @James: Good point. I guess it's a bad habit of mine to always use `stringstream` even if `ostringstream` or `istringstream` would suffice.

Comment: @James: what's the difference between istringstream and stringstream?

Comment: @ghiboz The same as the difference between `ifstream` and `fstream`. `stringstream` is bidirectional, with all of the extra management that that imposes.  (In practice, I never use bidirectional streams; the idiom isn't really appropriate, and they have different semantics according to the stream type.)

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void mung( istream & is ) {
    char c;
    while( is >> c ) {
        cout << c << endl;
    }
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
    if ( argc > 1 ) {
        ifstream ifs( argv[1] );
        mung( ifs );
    }
    else {
        istringstream iss( "here is some text to mung" );
        mung( iss );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, you can use `std::istringstream`, but in this case,
I'd prefer the deprecated (but always present) `std::istrstream`.  Or
simply create a simple `memory_streambuf`, with an `imemorystream` and
an `omemorystream`: if you don't need to be bidirectional, nor support
seeking, the `memory_streambuf` is less than 10 lines of code, is always
useful, and leaves out a lot of the complexity of the other solutions.
(If you're only doing this once, of course, using an existing solution
is to be preferred.  But I've found `memory_streambuf` to be useful in
a number of cases.)

Comment: As a matter of interest, why the preference for istrstream?

Comment: @unaperson Simplicity.  And maybe habit, to a degree, but if he has a `char[]` (pointed to by a `char*`), then `istrstream` can use it directly; `istringstream` will require conversion to `string`.  Not a big deal, and if `istrstream` wasn't available, I'd use `istringstream`, but since it is, why not use the stream which can do exactly what you need.  (For output, the difference is more significant, since `ostrstream` will stop and declare error when you output too many characters.)